# Really confused about this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context

> He liked his warmed, though on TV ads he would demolish them toasted, the butter just melting, with an irresistible crunching sound.

The writer is actually talking about bagels. I was little confused when I read the line “He liked his warmed," cause there is no subject there. Also, no auxiliary verb is found in the line "the butter just melting" . Are they grammatically correct?

Comment: Context, context. _His_ refers to _his bagels_, as should be clear from the context: Everybody likes fresh bread, but I like _mine_ a couple of days old.

Comment: Remember that "his" can be either a possessive adjective (his choice) or a possessive pronoun (I didn't like my choice but I loved his)

Comment: He liked his [to be] warmed.

Comment: Yes, context. Is he an actor in the ads?

Answer (score 1):

With more words added, in `[square brackets]` -

> He liked his [bagels] warmed, though on TV ads he would [eat] [his bagels] toasted, the butter [on the bagels] just melting, with an irresistible crunching sound [as he ate them].

I'm inferring that the man in question (call him *John Doe*) is a TV spokesperson for the bagel company, who is portrayed on TV as liking his bagels toasted. However, back in reality, he prefers his bagels simply warmed, not toasted.

**You, the reader, are supposed to infer that the subject of this sentence is John's Bagels.**

We can guess at more context:

> John Doe was a TV spokesperson for the Generic Bagel Company.
>
> He liked his [bagels] warmed, though on TV ads he would demolish [his bagels] toasted, the butter [on the bagels] just melting, with an irresistible crunching sound [as he ate them].

My spellchecker is complaining about the <kbd>though</kbd>, claiming that it should be <kbd>through</kbd>. Don't worry, <kbd>though</kbd> is correct here.